# How to launch libgdx example?

Tags: java, libgdx

I am trying to learn how to use socket in libgdx.
I'm trying to run the example, I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

i try to run this example:
https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/04094910142d11ee4028a4263ceb2597c2d9815f/tests/gdx-tests/src/com/badlogic/gdx/tests/net/PingPongSocketExample.java#L36

DesktopLauncher.java:

```
package com.nexlab.testing.desktop;
import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl3.Lwjgl3Application;
import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl3.Lwjgl3ApplicationConfiguration;
import com.nexlab.testing.PingPongSocketExample;
import com.nexlab.testing.Testing;

public class DesktopLauncher {
    public static void main (String[] arg) {

        PingPongSocketExample sss = new PingPongSocketExample();
        sss.create();

        Lwjgl3ApplicationConfiguration config = new Lwjgl3ApplicationConfiguration();
        new Lwjgl3Application(new Testing(), config);
    }
}
```

PingPongSocketExample.java:

```
package com.nexlab.testing;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Net.Protocol;
import com.badlogic.gdx.net.ServerSocket;
import com.badlogic.gdx.net.ServerSocketHints;
import com.badlogic.gdx.net.Socket;
import com.badlogic.gdx.net.SocketHints;

/** Demonstrates how to do very simple socket programming. Implements a classic PING-PONG sequence, client connects to server,
 * sends message, server sends message back to client. Both client and server run locally. We quit as soon as the client received
 * the PONG message from the server. This example won't work in HTML. Messages are delimited by the new line character, so we can
 * use a {@link BufferedReader}.
 * @author badlogic */
public class PingPongSocketExample extends GdxTest {
    @Override
    public void create () {
        System.out.println("!!!!!: 000");
        // setup a server thread where we wait for incoming connections
        // to the server
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run () {
                System.out.println("!!!!!: 111");
                ServerSocketHints hints = new ServerSocketHints();
                ServerSocket server = Gdx.net.newServerSocket(Protocol.TCP, "localhost", 1381, hints);
                // wait for the next client connection
                Socket client = server.accept(null);
                // read message and send it back
                try {
                    String message = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream())).readLine();
                    Gdx.app.log("PingPongSocketExample", "got client message: " + message);
                    System.out.println("!!!!!: got client message: " + message);
                    client.getOutputStream().write("PONG\n".getBytes());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Gdx.app.log("PingPongSocketExample", "an error occured", e);
                    System.out.println("!!!!!: an error occured");
                }
            }
        }).start();

        // create the client send a message, then wait for the
        // server to reply
        System.out.println("!!!!!: 222");
        SocketHints hints = new SocketHints();
        Socket client = Gdx.net.newClientSocket(Protocol.TCP, "localhost", 1381, hints);
        try {
            client.getOutputStream().write("PING\n".getBytes());
            String response = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream())).readLine();
            Gdx.app.log("PingPongSocketExample", "got server message: " + response);
            System.out.println("!!!!!: got server message: " + response);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Gdx.app.log("PingPongSocketExample", "an error occured", e);
            System.out.println("!!!!!: an error occured");
        }
    }
}
```

Log:

```
Executing tasks: [DesktopLauncher.main()] in project /Users/nexus/Nexus/dev_android/libgdx/testing

> Task :core:compileJava
> Task :core:processResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :core:classes
> Task :core:jar
> Task :desktop:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
> Task :desktop:processResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :desktop:classes UP-TO-DATE

> Task :desktop:DesktopLauncher.main() FAILED
!!!!!: 000
!!!!!: 222
!!!!!: 111
Exception in thread "main" Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.nexlab.testing.PingPongSocketExample.create(PingPongSocketExample.java:50)
    at com.nexlab.testing.desktop.DesktopLauncher.main(DesktopLauncher.java:14)
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.nexlab.testing.PingPongSocketExample$1.run(PingPongSocketExample.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':desktop:DesktopLauncher.main()'.
> Process 'command '/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 269ms
5 actionable tasks: 3 executed, 2 up-to-date
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your Testing class is, but to run this example directly, it needs to be your ApplicationListener that you pass to `initialize()`:

```
public class DesktopLauncher {
    public static void main (String[] arg) {
        Lwjgl3ApplicationConfiguration config = new Lwjgl3ApplicationConfiguration();
        new Lwjgl3Application(new PingPongSocketExample(), config);
    }
}
```